# How to share folder file in the system on JBOSS 7.1?

Tags: jboss

I have this issue, I want to share the contain of a certain folder in my filesytem on JBOSS is possible ?
Thank you

Comment: add more information..

Comment: @ORION : I have a batch programm that store some file in directory every 10 minutes in BatchFolderDir. The files inside this directory have to be reachable from URL. When i clicked in the url i can downloaded this file. How can view BatchFolderDir from Jboss for publish the link ?

Comment: you could start with giving the chown and chmod permissions to the user you start jboss with